# why Order by does not sort?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query below, I want it to sort the data by `id`, but it doesn't sort at all.

```
Select distinct ec.category,ec.id
from print ec
order by ec.id asc
```

What could be the reason?

this is the output :

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of `id`?? also add some sample data from that table and that column `id`.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does work, but maybe not as you expect it to sort. What did you expect?

Comment: `id` is presumably a string.

Comment: If you are storing numbers as text, then the sorting will be alphabetical, not numerical. Convert to number first if that is the case.

Comment: yeah id is a string should i change it to numbers ?

Comment: @CengizDogan Yes or cast it to `Integer` in `order by` clause

Comment: You can convert your column ad hoc to a number data type, and get it sorted that way. Use `TO_NUMBER`, or have the column be a number in the first place. Be aware that if 1 record holds something that is not a number, all may fail. You should ask yourself : why are you storing numbers in an alfa field ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your data, the column data type is a `varchar`, aka 'text'.

If it is text, it sorts like text, according to the place the character occurs in the character set used.

So each column is ordered on the first character, then the second, etc. So `2` comes after `11`.

Either make the column a numeric data type, like `number`, or use `to_number` in the sorting:

```
select distinct ec.category,ec.id
from print ec
order by to_number(ec.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference lies in the way `varchar` and `number` are sorted. in your case, since you have used `varchar` data type to store `number`, the sorting is done for the `ASCII` values.

**NUMBERS when sorted as STRING**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT LEVEL rn FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < = 11
  3  )
  4  SELECT rn, ascii(rn) FROM DATA
  5  order by ascii(rn)
  6  /

        RN  ASCII(RN)
---------- ----------
         1         49
        11         49
        10         49
         2         50
         3         51
         4         52
         5         53
         6         54
         7         55
         8         56
         9         57

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you can see, the sorting is based on the `ASCII` values.

**NUMBER when sorted as a NUMBER itself**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT LEVEL rn FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < = 11
  3  )
  4  SELECT rn, ascii(rn) FROM DATA
  5  ORDER BY rn
  6  /

        RN  ASCII(RN)
---------- ----------
         1         49
         2         50
         3         51
         4         52
         5         53
         6         54
         7         55
         8         56
         9         57
        10         49
        11         49

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**How to fix the issue?**

Change the data type to `NUMBER`. As a workaround, you could use `to_number`.

Using `to_number` -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT to_char(LEVEL) rn FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < = 11
  3  )
  4  SELECT rn, ascii(rn) FROM DATA
  5  ORDER BY to_number(rn)
  6  /

RN   ASCII(RN)
--- ----------
1           49
2           50
3           51
4           52
5           53
6           54
7           55
8           56
9           57
10          49
11          49

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the type of your "id" column is int. (integer = number)

Right now it is probably text, char or varchar(for text, strings).

You can't sort numbers alphabetically or strings/text chronologically like you are trying now.

Answer (score 0):

when you sort a string datatype that has in values it produce result as

1

10

11

2

21 etc...

Hence

> Change your Id datatype to int/bigint

Answer (score 0):

You can only just cast/convert the datatype in a query

Select distinct ec.category,ec.id
from print ec
order by cast(ec.id as int) asc